# Is there a shorthand to create member variables from function arguments in python?

Tags: python, attributes

Suppose I have a constructor in python:

```
 def __init__(self, bBoolFlags_a_Plenty):
     self.bBoolFlags_a_Plenty = self.bBoolFlags_a_Plenty
     [...]  # one line for each bool flag passed in.
```

Is there a way to assign function arguments passed to init() to member variables/attributes of the class having the same name as the function arguments without having to hand write each one?

Of something more limited in scope, perhaps a one liner will do.  Something like:

```
self.* = ( arg_bool1, arg_bool2, arg_bool3, arg_bool4)
```

Actually, I would prefer the latter, just because I don't want the 'kitchen sink' to be assigned to self.

thanks.

Comment: `( arg_bool1, arg_bool2, arg_bool3, arg_bool4 )` Would a list not be better for this purpose? Then you could pass in `bool_args` and assign it using `self.bool_args = bool_args`.

Comment: if you find yourself needing a method which requires more than a couple of arguments then you should reconsider your design.

Comment: More than a couple?  2 you mean?  That's hard to do... for me.  :)  But, I will see.  Thanks for the feedback.  I often have about 5 args.  But often I find, myself assigning self.Name = Name alot, and I want to know if there's a shorthand for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use `kwargs`:

```
def __init__(self, **flags):
    for flag, value in flags.iteritems():
        setattr(self, flag, value)
```

Or as @bgporter correctly suggests use the `__dict__` directly (assuming that you don't define the [**__slots__**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) attribute):

```
def __init__(self, **flags):
    self.__dict__.update(flags)
```

Depending on what number "plenty" actually specifies, it may however be easier to keep them in a seperate dict anyway:

```
def __init__(self, **flags):
    self.flags = flags
```

I'd favour the latter possibility especially if the class has other, "non-flag" attributes as well.

Comment: even easier, you can do `self.__dict__.update(flags)`

Comment: @bgporter not every class is guaranteed to have a `__dict__` (though arguably if the OP is messing around with `__slots__` then they should know enough already to know this...:) )

Comment: Wow, thanks for this answer.  You've given lots of options and some new things of python to look at.  I will play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also:

```
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for key in iter(kwargs):
        settatr(self, key, kwargs.get(key))
```